# What is the path of my module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

This is my first time with Drupal 7, i wrote a test module that echo "test" , and in the menu the path is "test".

When i'm trying to access localhost/drupal/test OR localhost/drupal/admin/test it can't find it, and i see 404 or admin page.

What is the problem here?

---

this is the code, and its doesnt work

```
<?php
/* $Id$ */

/**
* @file
* Very simple DRUPAL module
*/

/**
* Implementation of hook_help().
*/
function hello_world_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'admin/help#hello_world':
      $output = '<p>Hello world help...</p>';
      return $output;
    case 'admin/modules#description':
      return 'Hello world module description...';
  }
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function hello_world_menu($may_cache) {
  $items = array();

  if ($may_cache) {
  }
  else {
    $items[] = array(
      'path' => 'hello', // drupal path example.com/?q=hello
      'title' => 'Hello world page...', // page title
      'callback' => 'hello_world_page', // callback function name
      'access' => TRUE, // every user can look at generated page
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK // define type of menu item as callback
    );
  }

  return $items;
}


/**
* Function which generate page (this generate any content - you need only your own code...)
*/
function hello_world_page() {
  return '<p>Hello world!</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This might help you on the way:
http://drupal.org/node/84658

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal 7 example module, page not found, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529513/drupal-7-example-module-page-not-found-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting you correctly,

1. you wrote a `hook_menu()` where you created a menu path test(say `$item['test']`) and wrote a page callback function.
2. In the page callback function, you say echo test.

If this is the scenario, you just **need to clear your cache**. Drupal needs to register the menu item. After writing any menu hook implementation, you should clear your cached data and then try again.

Answer (score 10):

Use [drupal_get_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) to get the path of your module or theme. If the name of your module is 'mymodule', then you'd simply invoke the below piece of code to get the path.

```
drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
```

**EDIT**

Reading your question again makes me realise that your'e asking for the URL to your module. Could you please post the code you've got in your module's hook_menu()?

Comment: I got here because of the title of the post, and although that wasn't what the OP was looking for it answered my question :)